# How can join 2 Table when Key are in different columns

Tags: sql, join

i have 2 Tables: accounthierarchy and accountvaluetotal.

the link between 2 Tables is account number. i want to join the table based on account number. But the account number of table "account hierarchy " is on different Level (column).

Can you please help me how to do it? Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accounthierarchy](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[level1] [int] NULL,
[level2] [int] NULL,
[level3] [int] NULL,
[level4] [int] NULL,
[level5] [int] NULL)

INSERT INTO  [dbo].[accounthierarchy] (ID,level1,Level2,level3,level4,level5)
VALUES
(1,100,null,null,null,null),
(2,100,110,null,null,null),
(3,100,110,1110,null,null),
(4,200,220,null,null,null),
(5,200,230,null,null,null),
(5,200,240,null,null,null),
(6,200,240,2410,null,null)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[accountvaluetotal](
[accountnumber] [int] NULL,
[values] [int] NULL
) 

insert into [dbo].[accountvaluetotal]
values
(1110,5000),
(220,7400),
(230,6200),
(2410,5600)
```

Comment: Identify your Primary and Foreign key(s) (use [edit]).

Comment: Hi everybody, sorry for misunderstanding, i would like to have the result like this:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis that the account number is the 'last' value in the accounthierarchy table;

```
SELECT ID, COALESCE(ac.level5,ac.level4,ac.level3,ac.level2,ac.level1) as AccountNumber
from [accounthierarchy] ac
```

Will then give you the the account number, to which you can then do a standard join

COALESCE gives the first non-null value from a list of values, so by going from level 5 to level 1, it will return whichever valid value it arrives at first.

Answer (score 1):

you can use INNER JOIN-

```
SELECT * 
FROM accounthierarchy
INNER JOIN accountvaluetotal
ON level13=accountnumber;
```